# Change Pygame Window Size Without Losing Content

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a program and I want to re-size the window without losing the content. In a sense, I want to crop the window. It is OK if content is cutoff. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
from pygame import *
main = display.set_mode((800,600))
main.fill((255,255,255))
running = True
while running:
    mx, my = mouse.get_pos()
    mb = mouse.get_pressed()
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False
    if mb[0] == 1:
        draw.circle(main, (102,204,102), (mx, my), 10)
    elif mb[2] == 1:
        main = display.set_mode((200,200))
    display.flip()
quit()
```

When I change the screen, it does not show what I drew on the screen. How can I keep the content and "crop" the content when I change the screen size? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to crop content from the right and bottom sides?

Comment: Just from the bottom. I used both in the example above, although that is not my actual program. I just want to resize the height by adjusting from the bottom

Comment: You should not use `main = display.set_mode`. It will only create another screen, not shrink it.

Comment: I thought about saving the screen, changing the size, and blitting the saved image on the new window. How could I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually not possible. The modules will only create a new screen and delete the old one, including the circles. I have been trying for hours but the pygame docs only list modules that create and delete screens. So unfortuantely you can't change the size of the screen without deleting your old one and making a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since you want to make your screen re-sizable, make sure you add the `RESIZABLE` flag when you initialize your screen.

```
main = display.set_mode((800,600), RESIZABLE, 32)
```

When this is initialized, your window will become re-sizable. But now, you can access the new size of your screen through the `VIDEORESIZE` event that is sent whenever you resize your screen.

```
for e in event.get():
    if e.type == QUIT:
        running = False
    if e.type == VIDEORESIZE:
        print e.w, e.h, e.size
```

Now you can see the new window dimensions. I also suggest removing

```
elif mb[2] == 1:
    main = display.set_mode((200,200))
```

because it only creates a new screen, not adjust it. And it won't work.

Comment: Do you specifically want 200x200 to be your screen dimensions? Or it can be "dynamic"?

Comment: I want it to basically toggle between 2 screen sizes when a button is clicked. I did not show that in my code but in my actual program I do that. So with SirBob's example, how can I change the size, not the user?